# UIView mask throws [CALayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

On an UIView when i assign a mask first time, it works fine.

```
CALayer *maskLayer = self.bgViewMask.layer;
self.collectionView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

But when i remove it by doing below and re-assign it, it throws the exception.

```
self.collectionView.layer.mask = nil;
```

I hope its because when i remove it by assigning nil, it also releases the bgViewMask and hence it throws the exception. Could someone help me here.

Comment: I don't understand how you "re-assign it" or assign it in the first place, there's no code where you set `mask` to anything but `nil`.

Comment: Sorry editted the question to show how i assign the mask

Comment: You need to show _where_ that code runs. What is `self.bgViewMask`? How is declared and where does it get its value from? If you want help, _show your code_.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you set `self.bgViewMask.layer` to nil. So you need to create a new layer for your collectionView:

```
self.collectionView.layer.mask = [[CALayer alloc] initWithLayer:self.bgViewMask.layer];
```